# Scala types and subtypes equivalent in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scala, generics, inheritance

We have the following code in scala:

```
abstract class Index[+T <: DimIndex]  **(DimIndex is an abstract class)**
class I_C extends Index[D_C] **(D_C is a class that extends DimIndex)**
```

I have translated this code to  python in this way:

```
class Index(DimIndex):
class I_C(D_C):
```

But here we have ignored the relation with the class Index.
How to do this correctly?

Comment: `class IC(Index)`. (The `D_C` and `DimIndex` stuff does not matter for the declaration). In general, trying to map scala class hierarchy to python literally may not be the best idea.

Comment: @Dima Thank you for you answer.